# Keybase "keybased.sock: connect n osuch file or directory"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keybase

I need to install keybase, and I followed the instructions available on the [official linux download page](https://keybase.io/docs/the_app/install_linux).

I executed the following commands:

```html
curl -O https://prerelease.keybase.io/keybase_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i keybase_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
run_keybase                         <-- problems here
```

Error:

> ▶ INFO Starting keybase.service.
>
> ▶ ERROR dial unix /run/user/1000/snap.vscode/keybase/keybased.sock: connect: no such file or directory

I have run the installation twice now, but in both cases i got this error.
When i try to run `keybase -d login` I get the same error after several of these ones:

> Failed to connect to socket (18): dial unix /run/user/1000/snap.vscode/keybase/keybased.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Any ideas on how to complete the installation?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The above error occured because I was running the command on the Visual Studio Code command line. After I changed to a regular terminal, the problem did not occur.

Comment: happened to me too, this is absurd